# jQuery offset().top giving different values for IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, offset, scrolltop

I am trying to create a fixed position header, but I can't do it in the normal pure CSS way as the site I am working one has the browser scroll disabled, with the full site in a scrollable div.

The issue is when I calculate the offset top of the header in my scrollable div, the result is different for IE (all versions, even Edge) as for Chrome, in which the header works as desired.

Here is my code:

```
var $content = $('#content'),
    $contentWrapper = $('#content-wrapper'),
    $header = $('header'),
    otop = 0;

$($content).scroll(function (obj) {

    if ((navigator.userAgent.match(/msie|trident/i)) || (/Edge\/12./i.test(navigator.userAgent))) {
        otop = $content.scrollTop();
        //otop *= -1;
        console.log("IE", otop);
    } else {
        otop = $contentWrapper.offset().top;
        otop *= -1;
        console.log("ELSE", otop);
    }

    $header.css('top', otop);

    if (otop > 10) {
        $header.addClass("scrolled");
    } else {
        $header.removeClass("scrolled");
    }
});
```

CSS:

```
header {
    padding: 20px 0 0;
    background-size: contain;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 10001;
    background-color: #e6e1dd;
    display: block;
    min-height: 126px;
}

#content-wrapper {
    position: relative;
}

#content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    z-index: 2;
    overflow: scroll;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    -o-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    background: #e6e1dd;
    box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,.4) 0 0 15px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="content-wrapper">
        <header>
            ...
        </header>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have read that offset().top doesn't work in IE, but scrollTop() returns 0 in all browsers and I have not managed to find any other alternatives. I have looked at lots of different stack overflow links and nothing has worked so far, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `I have read that offset().top doesn't work in IE` It is normalized AFAIK. FYI, `$($content)` is useless, just use `$content`

Comment: Where did you read that `$offset().top` doesn't work in IE? And have you actually tried it? One of the main reasons for wanting to use jQuery at all is that it saves you having to do all those browser-specific bits. `$().offset()` and `$().scrolltop()` should both work as expected across all supported browsers.

Comment: Thanks @A.Wolff for pointing out the error, I've changed to just $content, but unfortunately it still doesn't work.

Comment: @Simba Yes, I have tried both methods extensively, but neither are working, hence why I am posting my code here, I must be missing something or have errors which I was hoping someone would notice.